# Access Denied creating a folder in a Samba Share from a windows client

Tags: 16.04, samba

I am a new user and please forgive my ignorance.

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 and am having trouble with file sharing.

Mission - give my workgroup read, write and execute access to a common drive on a Standalone Server based on a user account.

Have spend a few hours trying the standard config and testing but can only write files as the user in which the share was created.  Have tried changing file level permission and added the user as admin users in the Samba Config file.

Just am now confused, the lines in the config file include the following:

```
[GDrive]
comment = shared document drive
path = "/home/techo1/Shared Files/GDrive"
valid users = techo1 techo2 techo3
admin users = techo1 techo2 techo3
read only = no
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
public = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

Also have altered the setfacl to give permission for techo2 and techo2 to have rwx access and these list with getfacl.

Am trying to connect from windows 7 clients, but there will be some windows 10 clients.

Thanks for the opportunity to post a question for this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After looking through another question here, I found a link on a question someone else had asked which was a good answer, which is listed below:

http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-file-server-ubuntu-14-04-samba/

So my problem was solved by:

1. Rebuilding the server to ensure all the settings I messed with were refreshed.
2. Followed the instructions on the website listed above.
3. It all worked.

Many thanks for to this community for being there and providing an answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. that 770 from the above link doesn't work for me.

I used `sudo chmod 777 /shares/project1/`